# how to solve the edges issue in hexagonal plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, hex

I'm a beginner and I hope to be clear in exposing the problem.

I created a matrix like this:

```
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 6 8 9 1 0 0]
 [0 0 4 6 5 4 0 0]
 [0 0 4 2 8 9 0 0]
 [0 0 1 3 6 7 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

the point is that I have to create a hexagonal plot in which the color scale represents the random numbers in the individual cells.
This is what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
n=4

A=np.zeros([2*n,2*n], dtype=int)
B=np.random.randint(1,10, size=(n,n))

A[2:6,2:6]=B


plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.imshow(A, origin=['lower'], cmap=plt.cm.Purples_r)
plt.colorbar()


x=[]
y=[]
for i in range (np.shape(A)[0]):
    for j in range (np.shape(A)[1]):
        N_occurence=A[i,j]
        print(N_occurence)
        for k in range (N_occurence):
            x=np.append(x, i)
            y=np.append(y, j)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.hexbin(x,y,gridsize=(10), cmap=plt.cm.Purples_r)
plt.xlim([1, 6])
plt.ylim([1, 6])
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

but I can not solve the problem of edges, I always get half hexagons and the plot is not accurate. Does anyone know a simpler way or a similar example?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? For example `N_occurence=A[i,j]` should be indented within the above for-loop, but I don't know how the rest should be indented.

Comment: The indentation of your code seems a little bit wrong for some lines. Why not add the complete code and the output figure to your question? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) seems to be the best way to describe your problem. Your code produces something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/NZhU0Et.png) for me. What do you want it to look like?

Comment: sorry there was a problem in transcribing the code! @Jayjayyy the image is just that and I wanted to know how I can arrange the edges so as not to have half hexagons. do I have to change the whole matrix setting?

Comment: Your code is still missing the `import` statements and initial values for `x` and `y`. It won't run like that after copy and paste. Please read the information about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your code. Concerning your problem: using `plt.xlim([1, 6])` and `plt.ylim([1, 6])` might be a quick workaround?

Comment: Now it's complete! sorry!
thanks for the tip, at least I partly solved my problem! @Jayjayyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not really sure, what you're looking for, but I guess you want to have a `imshow` plot which uses hexagons like `hexbin`?

Maybe this helps a little bit:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate array
A = np.zeros([8, 8], dtype=int)
A[2:6, 2:6] = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(4, 4))

# Print array
print(A)

# `imshow` plot
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.imshow(A, extent=(0, 8, 0, 8), origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()

# Rewrite array to get x and y values
# TODO: There has to be a better way than to use two `for` loops
X = []
Y = []
for y in range(len(A)):
    for x, n in enumerate(A[len(A)-y-1]):
        X += [x]*n
        Y += [y]*n

# `scatter` plot to visualize rewritten array data
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.scatter(X, Y)

# `hexbin` plot
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.hexbin(X, Y, gridsize=5, extent=(0, 7, 0, 7))
plt.colorbar()

# show plots
plt.show()
```

Which results for random array `A`

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 3 7 3 3 0 0]
 [0 0 3 5 8 1 0 0]
 [0 0 4 8 7 3 0 0]
 [0 0 1 7 9 3 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

in

`imshow`
[image: imshow]

`scatter`
[image: scatter]

`hexbin`
[image: hexbin]

I think you might be better off with a custom solution like a scatterplot plotting hexagon tiles with your specified color.

Comment: This representation was a great help! I try to explain what I'm doing:
I'm writing a program that simulates the behavior of an avalanche through a cellular automaton. It is simulated by a matrix whose cells are hexagonal. 

the problem I'm trying to solve is the following:
I would like to have a graphical representation of these hexagons but I can not find any other way except through hexbin, but being a histogram it does not help me much.
@Jayjayyy